# Derivative bounded above, limit at boundary

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with $f'(x)<1,\forall x\ \in (0,1)$.

**Show:** $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(\frac{1}{n})$ exists (could be infinity).

First I noticed that $f'$ is not necessarily bounded, so we can't claim it's uniformly continuous. So $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(\frac{1}{n})$ could be negative infinity. Also the example $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ shows even if $f'$ is not bounded below, $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(\frac{1}{n})$ can still be real number. So at first I thought I could discuss different cases but now it seems the cases are mixed together.

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$ seems to be a counterexample. Are you sure the assumption isn't $|f'(x)|<1$?

Comment: f(x) = 1/x would be the case where the limit is negative infinity that I mentioned.

Comment: So by "exists" you allow $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\frac1n)=-\infty$? You should say that in the problem statement (it's not the default assumption.)

Comment: Thanks. Edited.

Comment: Hint: $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\frac1n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{1/n}^{1/2} f'(x)\,dx = \int_0^{1/2} f'(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't learnt integration yet. I don't know when to interchange the limit and integration operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Then $g'(x)<0$ so $g$ is decreasing. This implies that $f(\frac 1 n) -\frac 1 n =g(\frac 1 n)  $ is increasing. Hence it as  a limit. Since $\frac 1 n \to 0$ it follows that $f(\frac 1 n)$ has a limit.

Comment: It needs to be bounded above to have a limit right?

Comment: @FluffySkye You have written 'could be infinity' in the question. Every increasing sequence of real numbers either converges to a finite limit or tends to infinity. You need boundedness only when you insist on a finite limit.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thanks!